# can we setvalidity on a angularjs form element from content scripts running in background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which enters data to form elements by changing its value. It works for normal HTML page but for Angular.js page it does not work as some manual intervention is required for that form element since ng-model directives are used for those webpages.

Our extension is written in Javascript and I want to change form element validity from Javascript side for angular element.

Is there any way to change that I tried keyboardevent also from Javascript side but it does not work.

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Have you tried to trigger a digest cycle after set up the value?

Comment: You need to use dispatch a 'change' event and/or use document.execCommand, look for the old answers that show how to do it if you need an example.